# Upload an image and save it as base64

Tags: node.js

First in nodejs, I have succeeded to upload an image (using multer) through postman. Now I am trying to save it not as a png/jpg file, but as a base64 encrypted text file on disk. Any suggestions ?

```js
const express=require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
const db=require('./config/config').get(process.env.NODE_ENV);
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');


const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    // Destination to store image     
    destination: 'images', 
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          cb(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() 
             + path.extname(file.originalname))
            // file.fieldname is name of the field (image)
            // path.extname get the uploaded file extension
    }
});

const imageUpload = multer({
    storage: imageStorage,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 1000000 // 1000000 Bytes = 1 MB
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
      if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg)$/)) { 
         // upload only png and jpg format
         return cb(new Error('Please upload a Image'))
       }
     cb(undefined, true)
  }
}) 


app.post('/api/uploadPicture', imageUpload.single('picture'), (req, res) => {
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path, {encoding: 'base64'});
    let buff = Buffer.from(contents).toString('base64');

    console.log(buff);
    res.send(req.file);
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message })
})
```

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 0):

I've some ready snippets which worked well for me before. But I've commented there the part where you save a file with exact image extension. Instead I've saved the file with "txt" extension as you want (in userController).

**routes/main.js**

```
router.post('/image/base64', multerUpload.single('image'), userController.uploadBase64Image);
```

**utils/multer.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            const filePath = path.join(__dirname, './../uploads');
            cb(null, filePath);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            const extension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
            const fileName = (new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 0) + '.' + extension;
            cb(null, fileName);
        }
    }),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2 // MB
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        let valid = (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png');
        cb(null, valid);
    },
});
```

**controllers/user.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.APP_PORT; // 3000
const appUrl = process.env.APP_URL; // http://127.0.0.1

const uploadBase64Image = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const encoded = req.body.image;
        const base64ToArray = encoded.split(";base64,");
        // const prefix = base64ToArray[0];
        // const extension = prefix.replace(/^data:image\//, '');
        const extension = 'txt';

        // if (extension === 'jpeg' || extension === 'jpg' || extension === 'png')
        // {
            const imageData = base64ToArray[1];
            const fileName = (new Date().getTime() / 1000|0) + '.' + extension;
            const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, './../uploads/') + fileName;
            fs.writeFileSync(imagePath, imageData,  { encoding: 'base64' });

            return res.status(201).json({
                error: false,
                message: "Base64 Image was successfully uploaded.",
                url: `${appUrl}:${port}/images/${fileName}`
            });
        // }
        // else {
        //     return res.status(403).json({
        //         error: true,
        //         message: "Base64 data not valid!",
        //     });
        // }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: true,
            message: e.message,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') "

Comment: I've just tested, it's [work for me](https://dropmefiles.com/RcLib). please test it like in image, also you can get base64 from [here](https://www.base64-image.de/). Past the base64 text in form-data as a "image" field

Comment: May I ask How look like code in client side ? @boolfalse

Comment: @Hunter the provided code was from the backend of a mobile app project, so the client side could be anything, as i've tested it with postman as for an API endpoint